# Knexjs 2 Join a table from another Schema

Tags: mysql, node.js

i'm trying to join a table from the database account into the database player. Table names are player, player and account, account. I have account_id in table player and id in table account.

So i tried this code but i get following error with `nodejs`:

> Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`account` on `player`.`account_id` = `account`.`id`' at line 1

This is my code:

`knex.withSchema('player').table('player').select('player.*').leftJoin(knex.withSchema('account').table('account'),'player.account_id','account.id')`

I have to use `Mysql 5.6`. Appreciate every solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any straightforward approach using `withSchema` as its one schema all over the builder block. I used `joinRaw()` in my use case.

```
knex.withSchema('player').table('player').select('player.*')
.joinRaw('left join ?? on ?? = ??',['account.account','player.account_id','account.id'])
```

**output:**

```
select `player`.* from `player`.`player` 
left join `account`.`account` on `player`.`account_id` = `account`.`id`
```

**Note:** Positional bindings ? are interpreted as values and ?? are interpreted as identifiers.